# R3 CORDA : Question about nodes info and additional node info directory

Tags: corda

I want to run networksbootstrapper to configure two nodes on different machines in corda network. Based on the documentation, I need to put all node info files from different machines/nodes in one directory and generate nodes info files in additional nodes infor folder.  But I am unable to find the nodes info file for sample example corDapp running on machine.Can you please help me find where I can get the node info file of each node and where will ne additional nodes info directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `cordapp-example` from https://github.com/corda/samples, using the `release-V4` branch:

- navigate to the `cordapp-example` directory
- run `./gradlew :workflows-kotlin:deployNodes`

the node directories will be in `workflows-kotlin\build\nodes`

Comment: Thanks Anthony for Answering the query. But I am unable to find the workflows-kotlin folder after the build was successful.

Comment: Are you definitely using the `release-V4` branch? In the `release-V3` branch the folder structure is different.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to go to kotlin-source\build\nodes. But there is no nodes info file or additional nodes info folder in folders for Nodes or separately.

Comment: I have cloned version 4 only

Comment: This is the workflows-kotlin folder: https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/cordapp-example/workflows-kotlin - I think you're either in a different repository or a different example cordapp

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I will try again n get back